# How to get service account list from AWS account using boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Can someone help me to understand about service accounts ? how can we check using AWS CLI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the description from the [official documentation:](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_users.html)

> An IAM user is a resource in IAM that has associated credentials and
>   permissions. An IAM user can represent a person or an application that
>   uses its credentials to make AWS requests. This is typically referred
>   to as a service account.

Here is the sample code

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('iam',aws_access_key_id="XXX",aws_secret_access_key="XXX") 

users = client.list_users()
for key in users['Users']:
    print key['UserName']
```

Answer (score 0):

The notion of a 'service account' is not an AWS thing. In IT generally, it's a user account specifically set up with long-term credentials that a server can use (as opposed to a person).

This is a bad thing. You don't ever want long-term credentials on your servers (and certainly not in your code or configuration). You should use auto-rotating credentials, such as available via IAM roles.